# Twitter followers count without token in javascript (2020)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter

I'm asking this because previous answers are outdated.

I need to get twitter follower count and ideally without using php and / or API tokens.
This code returns an error:

```js
  var twitter_username = 'billgates';
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json?screen_names=" + twitter_username,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data[0]['followers_count']);
    }).fail(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The error is being return is the following:

```
   (index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json?screen_names=billgates&callback=jQuery112406752686864999666_1594556812284&_=1594556812285' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

although direct url access from browser does return json file.

Can it be fixed or currently no way to get followers count without api?

Comment: `dataType: 'jsonp',` — it's JSON, not JSONP

Comment: `crossDomain: true` — There's no point in setting this explicitly unless you are making a *same-origin* request that gets **redirected** to be cross-origin.